# Redirect all requests to HTTPS AND www to non-www

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm fixing my Apache (2.4.12) config files on a server that serves three different domain names. I have a different config file for each site. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to accomplish both of the following:

1. Redirect all `http` requests to `https`, keeping the entire rest of the request (subdomain/host AND document path) exactly the same
2. Redirect all `www` requests to non-`www`

I've read that this can be done in one step if I have only one `*:80` VirtualHost and put the rewrite rules there (the remainder of my subdomains are all `*:443` VirtualHosts with the exception of `www`), but I can't figure out how to do it. These answers on SO did not work:

- The accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945655/apache-redirect-http-to-https-and-www-to-non-www) is not correct (only does the `https` redirect)
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204124/i-want-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https-and-all-www-requests-to-non-www) does not work for me--only the `https` redirect works.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26914426/htaccess-rewrite-from-http-to-https-and-www-to-non-www) doesn't deal with a wildcard subdomain and is thus inapplicable.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29088257/htaccess-redirect-domain-to-https-subdomain-to-http-and-www-to-non-www) is also inapplicable because it doesn't deal with subdomains.

**EDIT:** This is the code I reference in the comments for [mike.k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31369664/1672458) below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is from my production system and works.

`THE_HOSTNAME` is for instance `server`, and then `THE_FQHN` is `server.domain.edu`, which helps for SSL certificates if you don't want to support wildcards and multiple domain names.

```
# redirect to FQHN
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} THE_HOSTNAME$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://THE_FQHN/ $1 [R=permanent,L]

# redirect to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://THE_FQHN%{REQUEST_URI}
```

In your case `www.domain.com` would be where `THE_HOSTNAME` is, and `THE_FQHN` would be `domain.com`, just flipped around

Comment: It appears that the `$1` on line 4 of your code shouldn't have a space before it (I get a syntax error). I'm testing now though and I'll let you know if it works with that space removed.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I used your code exactly how you put it (with the `$1` fixed per my previous comment) but with my hostname info. The `https` redirect works correctly, but the `www` isn't removed. I'm adding the exact setup to the OP so you can see it.

Comment: You were right about the space, I introduced it with careless typing. Put the `$` at the end of `www.example.com` in your Edit, so `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example.com$`